# React Parsing Error. Functions vs Classes

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-router

I've got a small page which retrieves JSON from an API and displays it as a bootstrap list. I'm currently moving this mammoth page into React and I'm setting up the components.

Note that I'm still very unclear on the proper usage of functions and classes. And this is where I suspect the issue lies.

I'm currently receiving the following error

```
Failed to compile.

./src/components/Events.js
  Line 3:10:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

  1 | import React from 'react'
  2 | 
> 3 | Function Events (){
    |          ^
  4 | const Events = ({ events }) => {
  5 |   return (
  6 |     <div>
```

My files are structured as below (some removed for clarity):

```
Public
 | index.html
src
  index.css
  index.js
  | components
      App.js
      Events.js
      Feed.js
      ...
```

I've added the following `App.js`, `Events.js` and `Feed.js`.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { Navigation, Footer, Home, Feed, Search, About, Contact } from "../components";


function App() {
  return (
<Router>


      <Navigation />

      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={() => <Home />} />
        <Route path="/feed" exact component={() => <Feed />} />
        <Route path="/search" exact component={() => <Search />} />
        <Route path="/about" exact component={() => <About />} />
        <Route path="/contact" exact component={() => <Contact />} />
      </Switch>

      <Footer />

    </Router>
  )
}

export default App
```

**Feed.js**

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import Events from '/components';

class Feed extends Component {

  state = {
  events: []
}

componentDidMount() {
  fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5002/events')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    this.setState({ events: data })
  })
  .catch(console.log)
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="feed">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center my-5">
          <div class="col-lg-7">
            <img
              class="img-fluid rounded mb-4 mb-lg-0"
              src="http://placehold.it/900x400"
              alt=""
            />
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-5">
            <h1 class="font-weight-light">Contact</h1>
            <p>
              Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
              industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
              ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of
              type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            </p>
          </div>
          <Events events={this.state.events} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
}
export default Feed;
```

**Events.js**

```
import React from 'react'

Function Events (){
const Events = ({ events }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <center><h1>Event List</h1></center>
      {events.map((event) => (
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{event.title}</h5>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{event.date}</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
};
}

export default Events
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is function declaration. With function declaration, you get hoisting straight out of the box which maybe beyond the scope of the question.

```
function myFunction() {}
```

This is a function expression.
The meaning of these code samples is the same: "create a function and put it into the variable myFunction".

```
const myFunction = () => {}
or 
const myFunction = function () {}
```

It is better if you read this -> https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/when-to-use-a-function-declarations-vs-a-function-expression-70f15152a0a0/

```
function Events({ events }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <center><h1>Event List</h1></center>
      {events.map((event) => (
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{event.title}</h5>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{event.date}</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: What's the error? I don't think there should be an error.

Comment: Its actually something different now so I'll mark this as the answer (capital F vs lower case f). The issue now is the following. `Attempted import error: '../components' does not contain a default export (imported as 'Events').` if you've any idea great. If not I'll create a separate question

Comment: There is something wrong with your imports. Update your code above. You have to export Events in your index.js inside your components.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Function Events ()` with `function Events()`.